# Custom non linear date x scale

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have data over time (consumption of gas, water, electricity) that I want to plot - from the past to today. But newer data is more important than older data. This is what I want as xaxis:

- Data from today till back one week - daily
- Data from one week till three weeks back - weekly
- Data older, monthly

The xticks would then would - roughly - look like this: `2022-05 2022-06 2022-07 2022-07-25 2022-08-01 2022-08-08 2022-08-09 2022-08-10 2022-08-11` **AND** would be equally spaced!. This would give me a good overview what happened yesterday, last week, and "in the entire past". However, I pretty much got stuck with the forward and reverse functions and the return values.
Does anyone have a example? I got this far only:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

def forward(x):
    return x
def reverse(x):
    return x

rng = pd.date_range(end='2022-08-14', periods=180, freq='D')

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': rng, 'Val': np.random.randn(len(rng)) }) 
df.set_index("Date",inplace=True)
ax=df.plot()
plt.gca().set_xscale('function', functions=(forward, reverse))

ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d'))
plt.xticks(rotation = 30)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use 3 horizontal subplots?

Comment: _... I pretty much got stuck with the forward and reverse functions ..._ - could you describe in details what's the exact problem? Also, I think that it would be better to transform the data, e.g. get mean values for old events, then trying to scale the plot.

Comment: three subplots were on my radar, but I halredy had subplots and adding more was not an option. Also it is almost impossible to put subplots together, that they look continuous.

Comment: @Falk I suggest you try `fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(1, 3, sharey= True,  gridspec_kw={'wspace': 0})` to get 3 plots with no space between them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Creating a custom scale for matplotlib

Two transformations are needed:

1. Compress each of the previous 3 weeks into the length of a day.
2. Compress each months, except the latest, into the length of a day.

Before any activity, let's simplify the data. I do it to avoid any hassle with `datetime`:

```
x = np.arange(120)
y = x
```

The main line is simple - if a date is earlier some endpoint then push it forward at the given scale. Since we compress data twice in the same manner, let's make a factory:

```
def compress_factory(endpoint, scale):
    return lambda x: scale * x + (1-scale) * endpoint
```

*Illustration for the formula above*
[image: illustration]

Now, prepare two pair of supportive functions, for the week and month:

```
w_ago = x[-1] - 7
w_forward = compress_factory(w_ago, 1/7)
w_backward = compress_factory(w_ago, 7)

m_ago = x[-1] - 30
leap = w_forward(m_ago) - m_ago
m_forward = lambda x: compress_factory(m_ago, 1/30)(x) + leap
m_backward = lambda x: compress_factory(m_ago, 30)(x - leap)
```

We apply them in two consequent `np.where` to separate scaling of the corrent week, previous 3 weeks and all the other dates:

```
def forward(x):
    return np.where(
        x > w_ago, 
        x,
        np.where(
            x > m_ago, 
            w_forward(x), 
            m_forward(x)
        )
    )

def backward(x):
    return np.where(
        x > w_ago, 
        x,
        np.where(
            x > w_forward(m_ago), 
            w_backward(x), 
            m_backward(x)
        )
    )
```

Take into account that in backward we compare data to transformed month endpoint. The first comparison stay the same because we don't scale the latest week.

Two sanity tests:

```
# 1. Does backward(forward(x)) equal x?
assert np.isclose(backward(forward(x)), x).all()
# 2. Is forward monotonic?
assert (((_:=forward(x))[1:] - _[:-1]) >= 0).all()
```

Let's see how it looks on simplified data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


x = np.arange(1, 91)
y = x  


def compress_factory(endpoint, size):
    return lambda x: size * x + (1-size) * endpoint

w_size = 7
w_ago = x[-1] - w_size
w_forward = compress_factory(w_ago, 1/w_size)
w_backward = compress_factory(w_ago, w_size)

m_size = 30
m_ago = x[-1] - m_size
leap = w_forward(m_ago) - m_ago
m_forward = lambda x: compress_factory(m_ago, 1/m_size)(x) + leap
m_backward = lambda x: compress_factory(m_ago, m_size)(x - leap)


def forward(x):
    return np.where(
        x > w_ago, 
        x,
        np.where(
            x > m_ago, 
            w_forward(x), 
            m_forward(x)
        )
    )


def backward(x):
    return np.where(
        x > w_ago, 
        x,
        np.where(
            x > w_forward(m_ago), 
            w_backward(x), 
            m_backward(x)
        )
    )


assert np.isclose(backward(forward(x)), x).all()
assert (((_:=forward(x))[1:] - _[:-1]) >= 0).all()


fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(16,5))
ax.plot(x, y)
ax.grid()
ax.set_xscale('function', functions=(forward, backward))
ax.set_xbound(min(x), max(x))
ax.set_ybound(min(y), max(y))
```

*Plot with custom scaling*
[image: plot with custom scale]

Comment: Thank you so much, I (finally) understood this axes scaling mechanism much better. However, Im going to go for the other solution proposed here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/73353288/7150174)

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np

idx = np.full(df.shape[0], False)
idx[-7:] = True
idx[-7:-3*7:-7] = True
idx[-3*7::-30] = True

df2 = df[idx]
print(df)
```

| Date | Val |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-02-25 00:00:00 | 1.1248252961101586 |
| 2022-03-27 00:00:00 | 0.04203875889903905 |
| 2022-04-26 00:00:00 | 0.5896163070537574 |
| 2022-05-26 00:00:00 | -1.8329001623876962 |
| 2022-06-25 00:00:00 | -1.0173128750157898 |
| 2022-07-25 00:00:00 | -0.6708114840150123 |
| 2022-08-01 00:00:00 | 0.2657251487401089 |
| 2022-08-08 00:00:00 | -0.6617901994374795 |
| 2022-08-09 00:00:00 | 0.17380650386233432 |
| 2022-08-10 00:00:00 | -0.13383053082508994 |
| 2022-08-11 00:00:00 | -1.1532937501757903 |
| 2022-08-12 00:00:00 | -0.5940972756876102 |
| 2022-08-13 00:00:00 | -0.9253845051895224 |
| 2022-08-14 00:00:00 | -0.5568183429382052 |

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(df2.index.astype(str), df2.Val);
plt.xticks(rotation=45);
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Thank you so much, I got stuck with requirement and solution space converting date to string and then plotting just the index was not on my radar and this is what does the job for me!